# Relation among numbers in a triangle like tartaglia:

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

I have a polynomial associate to a number: 
$$\begin{align}
k&=1 &n-1\\
k&=2 &n^2-2n +2\\
k&=3 &n^3-3n^2+6n+6\\
k&=4 &n^4-4n^3+12n^2-24n+24 
\end{align}$$

and in general$$ P(k+1)=n^k-(k+1)P(k)$$

Can those polynomials be expressed in terms of negative binomial coefficients?

In other words I am searching for a general formula to express those polynomials

Comment: In general, you must mean $P(k+1)=n^{k+1}-...$.

Comment: Also, row 3 should be $$n^3-3n^2+6n-6$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+1%2C+3%2C+6%2C+6%2C+1%2C+4%2C+12%2C+24%2C+24&sort=&language=english&go=Search), there is an unsigned integer sequence with your coefficients.

Now they have one good mathematica routine there, namely

`CoefficientList[Series[(1 + x)^m, {x, 0, 20}], x]*
   Table[n!, {n, 0, m}], {m, 0, 10}] // Grid`

I made this nested table, which I prefer, straight from the formula on OEIS (top of the page) to do the same thing, and modified it to include the alternating sign behavior:

`Table[Table[(-1)^k*n!/(n - k)! , {k, 0, n}], {n, 0, 8}] // Grid`

The result is

\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -2 & 2 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -3 & 6 & -6 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -4 & 12 & -24 & 24 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -5 & 20 & -60 & 120 & -120 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -6 & 30 & -120 & 360 & -720 & 720 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -7 & 42 & -210 & 840 & -2520 & 5040 & -5040 & \text{} \\
 1 & -8 & 56 & -336 & 1680 & -6720 & 20160 & -40320 & 40320 \\
\end{array}

I am taking your formula to be

$$P(k+1)=n^{k+1}-(k+1)P(k).$$

Thus I have that with the alternating sign behavior, the coefficients of the $n^{th}$ row $R_n$ of your sequence is given by the sequence formula

$$R_n=\mathop{\left\{ (-1)^k\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \right\}}\limits_{k=0}^{n}.$$

For example, row 4 is

$$R_4=\mathop{\left\{ (-1)^k\frac{4!}{(4-k)!} \right\}}\limits_{k=0}^{4}=\{ 1,-4,12,-24,24 \}.$$

Changing variable names so that we can use your $n$ in the polynomial base along with the coefficients, I manage to exactly duplicate your polynomial terms, and say that the $t^{th}$ row polynomial is given by the sum

$$R_t=\sum_{k=0}^t(-1)^k\frac{t!}{(t-k)!}n^{t-k}.$$

For completeness, I conclude with another Mathematica routine to duplicate your rows:

`Table[TraditionalForm[
   Sum[(-1)^k*t!/(t - k)!*n^(t - k), {k, 0, t}]], {t, 1, 8}] // TableForm`

The output of that is

\begin{array}{l}
 n-1 \\
 n^2-2 n+2 \\
 n^3-3 n^2+6 n-6 \\
 n^4-4 n^3+12 n^2-24 n+24 \\
 n^5-5 n^4+20 n^3-60 n^2+120 n-120 \\
 n^6-6 n^5+30 n^4-120 n^3+360 n^2-720 n+720 \\
 n^7-7 n^6+42 n^5-210 n^4+840 n^3-2520 n^2+5040 n-5040 \\
 n^8-8 n^7+56 n^6-336 n^5+1680 n^4-6720 n^3+20160 n^2-40320 n+40320 \\
\end{array}

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but it seems that it follow this rule

$$P(n)=n!+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k (n)_k\cdot x^{n-k}$$

Anyway it seems they are some mistake on the body of the question.